# LEFT JOIN How to use group by for multiple matches and return count of one column data

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables `Student` and `Grade`, when I use LEFT JOIN, if one `Student` matches multiple rows in `Grade`, it will all return so the total count is not correct. Below is my structure:

Student:

```
[OBJECT_ID] [int] NOT NULL,
```

Grade:

```
[ID][int] NOT NULL,
[OBJECT_ID] [int] NOT NULL,
[LEVEL] [int] NOT NULL
```

I want to get each student 's best grade (1,2,3 for 1 is the best) and calculate the amount of each level

```
select isnull(LEVEL,0) LEVEL ,count(*) as TOTAL_NUM from
       (select * from Student obj) T1

LEFT JOIN 
       (select  ID,OBJECT_ID,LEVEL from Grade) T2 
on T1.OBJECT_ID = T2.OBJECT_ID
group by LEVEL
```

It works when there are  only one match in Grade table. However, if one student has multiple grades, then it will return multiple student rows so the result is not correct.

For example, if one student has 1,2,3 grades, it only considers the grade 1 to count.

I just need to return all amount of each level and the SUM of each `TOTAL_NUM` equals to the rows of `Student` table.

Comment: Any chance of sample data and expected results. Also, I think the `TOTAL_NUM` for each `LEVEL` is missing from your `Grade` table.

Comment: @Peter Smith TOTAL_NUM is not  a column in table it just a alias for my count.The result will show two colums only LEVEL | TOTAL_NUM

Comment: Edit your question and show the results you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do a double aggregation. A first one to determine the level for each student (`min()`) and a second one to count the number of students on each level (`count()`).

**Sample data**

```
create table student
(
  [OBJECT_ID] [int] NOT NULL
);

insert into student (object_id) values
(1),
(2),
(3);

create table grade
(
  [ID][int] NOT NULL,
  [OBJECT_ID] [int] NOT NULL,
  [LEVEL] [int] NOT NULL
);

insert into grade (id, object_id, level) values
(100, 1, 1),
(101, 1, 2),
(102, 1, 2), -- student 1 has 1x level 1 and 2x level 2 grades
(200, 2, 1),
(201, 2, 3), -- student 2 has 1x level 1 and 1x level 3 grades
(300, 3, 2),
(301, 3, 2),
(302, 3, 3); -- student 3 has 2x level 2 and 1x level 3 grades
```

With this sample data there are 2 "level 1" students and 1 "level 2" student.

**Version with CTE**

```
with cte as
(
  select min(g.level) as level
  from grade g
  group by g.object_id
)
select cte.level,
       count(1) as total_num
from cte
group by cte.level
order by cte.level;
```

**Version with subquery**

```
select x.level,
       count(1) as total_num
from (
       select min(g.level) as level
       from grade g
       group by g.object_id
     ) x
group by x.level
order by x.level;
```

**Result**

```
level total_num
----- ---------
1     2
2     1
```

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=68d9e64636550032d649358162296704) to see everything in action.